# How to add authorize token to js function to download file function?

Tags: javascript, blazor, authorization, unauthorized

I have a blazor client and there's a function need to download a file.

I have a look at [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#download-from-a-url). It works if I set the API endpoint to allow anonymous. But when I set API endpoint with `[Authorize]`, I don't know how to pass the bearer token to the request.

I can pass the token to the last parameter of the function `triggerFileDownload` but not sure how to put it in the request.

I have tried as below but didn't work, got the 401 Unauthorized:

```
window.triggerFileDownload = (fileName, url, token) => {

const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
createCookie('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token, 1);//this line didn't work
anchorElement.href = url;
anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
anchorElement.click();
anchorElement.remove();
}


function createCookie(name, value, days) {
var expires;
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else {
    expires = "";
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

When I open the tab Network in browser, I see:

[image]

Please can anyone suggest how to pass the token to the request to this function? I think it would be something needed to be done in the code marked with comment (//this line didn't work).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bearer tokens usually don't belong to cookie, but to own Authorization header. To set header you will need to use `fetch` instead of anchorElement. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization header should be pass in the headers and I don't think it's possible directly when you click on a button.
Another way is to use a xhr call to download the file and pass the Authorization bearer token

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const origin = location.origin;
            const filename = 'fileToDownload.csv';
            const token = 'XXXXXXXX';
            function downloadFile() {
                const fileUrl = [origin, filename].join('/');
                fetch(fileUrl, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    })
                })
                .then(function (response) { return response.blob();})
                .then(function (blob) {
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    console.log(url);
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a); // we need to append the element to the dom -> otherwise it will not work in firefox
                    a.click();    
                    a.remove();  //afterwards we remove the element again  
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Download file</h1>
        <div>
            <button onclick="downloadFile()" type="button">download file</button>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But do you know how to open the download link in a new tab? I add  "a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');" just underneath "var a = document.createElement('a');" but didn't open a new tab.